# Remove index.html with htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have duplicated pages across our website, we need to redirect anything that ends index.html to the non index.html for example;

/van-insurance/pick-up-insurance.html
301 Redirects to 
/van-insurance/pick-up-insurance

/van-insurance/private.html
301 Redirects to 
/van-insurance/private

What would be the htaccess code for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am afraid this did nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\.html $1
```

Documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch